# I can't type on input and change this in react redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an issue with this code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hghsyk?file=reducers%2Findex.js
I can't type on inputs and don't why for??

Comment: can you elaborate your question? What is it that you expect and is not working? I edit your field and it retains the value.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your App.js :

replace

```
value={input}
```

with

```
defaultValue={input}
```

**Or use**

```
onChange={(e) => dispatch(editValue(e.target.value,item.id)) }
```

Comment: thanks that's work

Comment: @RE7A, glad this help you, will you please also accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You just need remove attribute value={input} then it will be okay.
Because when you set attribute value, the input become "controlled".